# HTML Table Cells - Hiding One Cell

Tags: html, css

I have a html table that I have setup in a 3 rows by 2 column formation. So basically have 6 cells that are currently being displayed to the suer.

My question is an unsure how to do, is that I only want to use 5 cells only visible to the user so would like to somehow remove cell position (3,2), so that it doesn't show any borders at all for that cell alone - can this be done, if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look up the css properties `border-collapse` and `empty-cells`

Ref: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html

Scroll down the page and look at the examples of `empty-cells:hide` also check the browser compatibility chart at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks @Moin. FYI, I have added empty-cells:hide into my style sheet and all seems to work fine but it leaves a grey color in place. Am I able to control this color as my site is on a white background?

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the CSS on the cell you want to hide to `visbility: hidden;` - that will not show the cell, but it'll still take up space. See the reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Comment: Thats make the cell relative, and collapsing border (if border applied) might dissapear, also any background color not produced, etc tec

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have cell at 3,2 as

```
<td id="cell32">cell data</td>
```

When you want to hide it, then execute

```
cell32 = document.getElementById("cell32");
cell32.style.display = "none";
```

However if you hide a middle cell, your other cells will shift left. To preserve table structure, you need to replace hidden cell with a special cell having `empty (&nbsp;)` content and no borders as you want.

Answer (score 1):

use `css` property `empty-cells` to remove unwanted/empty cells from table. When the `empty-cells: hide` used, the empty cells will be completely erased from the table view as shown,

[image: table]

moreover, when the `empty-cells: hide` and still you want to display some of the cells which are empty, you can override the behavior by using `&nbsp;` in empty cells. for more information, you can visit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/empty-cells)